# What is wrong with my code? (crashes right when code is executed)

Tags: java, android

It has no errors, but when I run it, it crashes. The portion of my code that I believe the problem is in is as follows:

```
    int h = (a * c);
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(h); i++) {
        if (h % i == 0)
            factors.add(i);
    }
    Integer result = null;
    for (int ii : factors) {
        if (b == ii + h / ii) {
            result = ii;
            // ax^2+hiix+iix+c
        }
        int hii = h / ii;
        int gcd1 = Euclid.getGcd(a, hii);
        int gcd2 = Euclid.getGcd(ii, c);
        String factored1 = ("(" + gcd1 + "x+" + gcd2 + ")");
        int fact21 = (a / gcd1);
        int fact22 = (hii / gcd1);
        String factored2 = ("(" + fact21 + "x+" + fact22 + ")");
        EditText tvfact1a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvfact1);
        EditText tvfact2a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvfact2);
        tvfact1a.setText(factored1);
        tvfact2a.setText(factored2);
    }
```

a and c are initialized earlier in the program. The Euclid class is as follows:

```
package boston.project;

public class Euclid {
    public static int getGcd(int a, int b) {
        while (b != 0) {
            if (a > b) {
                a -= b;
            } else {
                b -= a;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

EDIT

LogCat

01-01 15:28:59.479: W/KeyCharacterMap(303): No keyboard for id 0
01-01 15:28:59.479: W/KeyCharacterMap(303): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-01 16:22:03.158: W/KeyCharacterMap(334): No keyboard for id 0
01-01 16:22:03.158: W/KeyCharacterMap(334): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-01 16:22:16.739: D/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
01-01 16:22:16.739: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at boston.project.TheBostonProjectActivity$1.onClick(TheBostonProjectActivity.java:138)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-01 16:22:16.759: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Crashes how? Anything in the log?

Comment: Your indentation makes the `for` cycle quite misleading — edited...

Comment: Is line 138 the findViewById shown? If so, start there. If not, what's that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error occurs because you are using a TextView in your layout but try to cast it to a EditText in your code.
You should change

```
EditText tvfact1a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvfact1);
EditText tvfact2a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvfact2);
```

to

```
TextView tvfact1a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfact1);
TextView tvfact2a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfact2);
```

Comment: You beat me to it. It's almost certainly the case. +1

Comment: Or it could be the other way around if the OP want's to accept user input. In other words they'd need to change the `TextView` elements in the layout file to be `EditText` and leave their code as it is.

Answer (score -2):

The problem might be in the line

`String factored1 = ("(" + gcd1 + "x+" + gcd2 + ")");`

Try explicitly changing `gcd1` and `gcd2` to Strings as follows:

`String factored1 = ("(" + Integer.toString(gcd1) + "x+" + Integer.toString(gcd2) + ")");`